# Java - how to map multiple ArrayLists in a HashMap using a loop

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm working on a homework assignment ([CS 106A, Handout #8](http://see.stanford.edu/materials/icspmcs106a/41-section-handout-8.pdf) ). It is a trip itinerary program where the user selects an origin and gets a list of potential destinations.

I'm stuck on the data storage section where I'm reading a text file (2nd page of pdf) and storing it. I chose to store data in a `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>`; where the key would be the trip origin and the value would be an `ArrayList` with all destinations available from the given origin.

This is the code I have so far (https://gist.github.com/cch5ng/8139898)

```
//imports

import acm.program.*;
import acm.io.*;
import acm.graphics.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.charset.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;

public class handout8 extends ConsoleProgram {

public void init() {
    //read in flights.txt data
    origin_old = "";
    Path file = Paths.get("flights.txt");
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("US-ASCII");
    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(file, charset)) {
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            origin_new = "";
            //System.out.println("origin_old: " + origin_old + ".");
            dest = "";
            //destinations.clear();
            int k = 0;
            while (line.charAt(k) != 0 && k < line.length() - 1 && line.charAt(k + 1) != 45) { //45 for -
                origin_new += Character.toString(line.charAt(k));
                k++;
            }
            if (line.length() > 1) {
                System.out.println("k: " + k);
                System.out.println("origin_old: " + origin_old + ".");
                System.out.println("origin new: " + origin_new + ".");
                if (k != 0) {
                    dest = line.substring(k + 3);
                }
                //issue here where all the keys end up with the same destinations array list
                //I know I can correctly get the number of origin cities, so maybe I need to hardcode the array list names somehow?
                if (origin_old.equals(origin_new)) {
                    destinations.add(dest);
                    System.out.println("added dest");
                } else {
                    destinations.clear();
                    System.out.println("cleared dest");
                    destinations.add(dest);
                }
                System.out.println("dest: " + dest);
                System.out.println("num destinations: " + destinations.size());
                //error in logic adding data to hashmap
                //issue here where all the keys end up with the same destinations array list
                //ArrayList<String> destin_old = new ArrayList<String>();
                //destin_old = destinations;
                if (!origin_new.equals("")) {
                    mp_destinations.put(origin_new, destinations);
                }

                origin_old = origin_new;
                printDest(origin_new);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        println("IOException: " + e);
    }
    printKeys();
    printDest("Denver");
    printDest("New York");
    //printDest("San Francisco");
    //printDest("San Jose");
    //printDest("Honolulu");
    //printDest("Anchorage");
}

private void printKeys() {
    Iterator it = mp_destinations.keySet().iterator();
    System.out.println("Origins: ");
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());
    }
}

private void printDest(String start) {
    ArrayList<String> dest2 = mp_destinations.get(start);
    if (dest2.size() > 1) {
        Iterator i = dest2.iterator();
        System.out.println("Destinations for " + start + ": ");
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Destination for " + start + ": " + dest2.get(0));
    }
}
//ivars
private ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> mp_destinations = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
private String origin_old, origin_new, dest;
}
```

(the issue seems to be around lines 50-67)
While looping through the lines of the text file, it appears the program is defining the keys and the respective ArrayList contents appropriately. However when I check the values of the HashMap at the very end, all the returned values are only appropriate for the last key added. I guess all the keys appear to be mapped to the same ArrayList.

Do I need to hardcode a unique ArrayList per number of keys? How do I define and maintain different ArrayLists (dynamically) per key (assuming I don't know the # of keys before running the program)? TIA.

Comment: Post the relevant code here, no one wants to follow links.

Comment: (Off-topic): Can you use Guava? If so, consider a [MultiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) to simplify dealing with `Map<K, List<V>>`

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: You need a unique `ArrayList` per key. or every key has the same set of values (which you clearly don't want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign a brand new `ArrayList` to `destinations` for each key of the map. Otherwise the keys will all be mapping to the same object.

Replace this line:

```
destinations.clear();
```

with

```
destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: notice that with the given code, you will have an error the second time a destination is added to existing origin, as it will replace the first destination with the second, instead of adding the second to it.

Answer (score 0):

you seem to misuse the HashMap put method.
whenever you call map.put you replace the current value stored with the new value given.
consider the following code snippet

```
ArrayList<String> destinations = new ArrayList<String>();
//add new destination
destinations.add("dest1");
destinations.add("dest2");

if (!origin_new.equals("")) {
    //before adding to map obtain the current list of destinations
    ArrayList<String> currentDestinations = mp_destinations.put(origin_new);
    if (currentDestinations == null)
        //if the origin doesn't exists, create the destinations list
        currentDestinations = new ArrayList<String>();

    //add all the new destinations to the list
    currentDestinations.addAll(destinations);

    //store the modified list in your map
    mp_destinations.put(origin_new, currentDestinations);                   
}
```

Comment: tzafrir, for each line of the text file I am reading, I'm checking whether the key (city of origin) is the same as the previous line's key. If so, I am updating the ArrayList of destinations. Then, if so, I do want to replace the mapping for that key with the updated ArrayList. You can argue that my program could be redesigned for efficiency but that was a design choice and works as expected. See:     if (origin_old.equals(origin_new)) {
                    destinations.add(dest);}

Comment: @cchung I was not aware that the list you are reading is sorted.
if the list is not sorted (e.g origin paris, origin london, origin paris) your code breaks. also, notice that in the case you mentioned
`if (origin_old.equals(origin_new)) { destinations.add(dest);}` there is no need to replace the value stored in the map, as you are actually modifying it when adding the second destination